# How to pass javascript array to java applet method?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, illegalargumentexception

I have applet that contains method:

```
public void send(byte[] arr) {
   ... //some code
}
```

But when I call this method from JS I get the error:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method found matching name send and arguments [sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject]*

If I set *send* method argument to String and then pass string argument from JS to applet, then it`s ok. No warnings.

**How to pass array from JS to java method correctly?**

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/js_java.html

Comment: @Mob there is no answer to my question on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html  contains some examples.

Javascript does not have a byte type, at least not in the browser.  Try passing in an the arguments as int[] or String[] and casting/converting in your applet to a byte array.